# Generic variable and function calling in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to find a way to use generic variable and function calling. Like setting a reference in react dynamically, depending on another variable.

An vision of what I would like to get is:

```
ref={ref => (eval(`this.${this.props.controlId}`) = ref)}
```

which would end up being something like

```
this.props.controlId = "myid"

ref={ref => (this.myid = ref)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can destruct the props like:

```
const { controlId : myId } = this.props; // renamed to myId
ref={ref => (this[myId] = ref)} // <---here you can use it.
```

---

In your case you can use `[]` notation for this:

```
ref={ref => (this[this.props.controlId]= ref)}
```

Comment: I don't see how the first suggestion solves the OP problem?

Comment: I guessed it can be used as `this[myId]`. @FelixKling

Comment: Yes, but you should add that. I would suspect the OP to try `this.myId` first.